# How to select template element by ID in Angular 2 Dart?

Tags: angular, dart, dart-html, angular2-dart

Relativley new to Angular and Dart I have the following problem:

my_component.dart:

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'package:angular2_components/angular2_components.dart';

import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';
import 'dart:html';


@Component(
  selector: 'google-route-map',
  styleUrls: const ['my_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'my_component.html',
  directives: const [materialDirectives],
  providers: const [materialProviders],
)
class MyComponent {

  MyComponent() {

    var m = querySelector("#my-canvas");

    print (m); // is null

    // do something with m....
  }
}
```

my_component.html:

```
<div id="my-canvas"></div>
```

As far as I have understood the problem is that `querySelector` queries *only the base dom not the shadowDom*.

However how do I simply query an id within my template?

Comment: It depends where `#my-canvas` comes from and how it is created. Your question doesn't contain any information about that. According to your edit it is part of a components template otherwise `@ViewChild()` wouldn't work - but `@ViewChild()` is not "select by ID". Therefore I'm a bit confused about your addition to my answer.

Comment: Yes its part of the components template. However with querySelector the element was still `null`. Is there another possibility to select by ID? Missed something maybe?

Comment: I updated my answer. That should work. But `@ViewChild()` is usually the better way for your use case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Move the code to `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild("mapCanvas")
  ElementRef canvas;

  @override
  void ngAfterViewInit() {
    DivElement m = canvas.nativeElement;
    ...
  }
}
```

When the constructor is executed, there is no DOM created yet for the component.

EDIT: Correct but Element was still null. Now works after accessing it in the way of Angular binding with ViewChild annotation.

```
<div #mapCanvas></div>
```

**update**

```
<div id="my-canvas"></div>
```

```
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ElementRef _elementRef;

  MyComponent(this._elementRef);

  @override
  void ngAfterViewInit() {
    var canvas = _elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector("#my-canvas");

  }
}
```

**update for AngularDart 5**

```
<div id="my-canvas"></div>
```

```
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  Element _element;

  MyComponent(this._element);

  @override
  void ngAfterViewInit() {
    var canvas = _element.querySelector("#my-canvas");

  }
}
```

Comment: This helped, a lot! Funny why this is not an official part of the documentaions. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to recent discussion in the AngularDart Gitter channel, a good way of doing this in AD5 would be:

```
@ViewChild(‘someRef’, read: HtmlElement)
CanvasElement someRefCanvas;
```

...or if the setting of the ViewChild happens after the view init (e.g. an *ngIf is involved), you can use a setter:

```
@ViewChild(‘someRef’, read: HtmlElement)
set someRefCanvas(CanvasElement e) {

}
```